# Passagem de dados de um fragment para outro

Tags: android, kotlin

Quero passar dados de um fragment para outro,porem o código funciona mas não passa os dados. Alguem pode me ajudar nisso?

Desejo passar de `ListaPokemonsFragment` para `DetalhesPokemonFragment`

`ListaPokemonsFragment`:

```
// acao de ir para os detalhes do pokemon clicado
private fun goToDetalhes(pokemon: PokemonItem){
    val direcao = ListaPokemonsFragmentDirections
        .actionListaPokemonsToDetalhesPokemons(pokemon)
    controlador.navigate(direcao)
}
```

`DetalhesPokemonFragment`

```
private fun configDetalhes() {
   viewModel.getDetalhes(pokemon.id)
    viewModel.mResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            tv_detalhes_nome_pokemon.text = it.body()?.nome
        }
    })
}
```

navigation:

```xml
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/detalhesPokemons"
  tools:layout="@layout/detalhes_pokemon"
  android:name="com.example.pokedex.ui.detalhesPokemons.DetalhesPokemonsFragment"
  android:label="Detalhes Pokemons" >
  <argument
      android:name="pokemon"
      app:argType="com.example.pokedex.model.PokemonItem" />
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Coloca seu argument dentro da action do fragmento inicial ( O que tem a ação de ir para um destino) por exemplo:

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/listPokemonsFragment"
        android:name="seu.pacote.aqui.ListPokemonsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_listPokemons"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_list_pokemons" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_listPokemonsFragment_to_DetalhesPokemonFragment"
            app:destination="@id/fragment_detalhes_pokemon">
            <argument
                android:name="pokemon"
                app:argType="com.example.pokedex.model.PokemonItem" />
        </action>
    </fragment>
```

- Em **DetalhesPokemonFragment** você vai receber o **PokemonItem** no bundle com o mesmo nome que você deu no atributo name do argument:

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            pokemonItem = it.getSerializable("pokemon")
        }
    }
```

*Vale lembrar que sua classe precisa implementar a interface Serializable ou Parcelable para enviar e receber no Bundle.* 
Você pode fazer isso consultando aqui
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784231/how-to-pass-custom-object-in-bundle

Comment: quando crio o onCreate, ele nao esta recebendo o "pokemonItem"

Comment: @MatheusFinamor você serializou o objeto? A resposta está bem clara, eu mesmo testei aqui e funcionou

Comment: Sim, resolvi o problema, ele estava dando erro com o meu Database. Ainda nao estou fazendo a persistencia de dados mas ja tinha deixado o database pronto, com ele pronto estava dando um conflito com meu "PokemonItem". Exclui minha classe Database e funcionou normalmente. Obrigado